# Optimising the number of observations by checking observation overlap in dataset

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataset with about 70.000 observations.

```
# A tibble: 71,789 x 31
   X1    Profit   CTR X2           Cr     Pr Riskaversion X2            A098  01  02  incidence_gov_f~ incidence_eth_f~ warhist peaceyears    Expop NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.~ SI.POV.GINI
   <dbl> <dbl+> <dbl> <dbl+>    <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl+lbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl+lbl>        <dbl+lbl>  
 1 100   NA        35  3           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 2 100   NA        35  3           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 3 100   NA        35  4           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 4 100   NA        35  5           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 5  20   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 6  10   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 7  15   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 8  18   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
 9   8   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
10   6   NA        35 NA           NA     NA           NA NA            NA    NA    NA                   0                0       5          1 0.620 4202.208         NA         
# ... with 71,779 more rows, and 13 more variables: tottax <dbl>, indiv <dbl>, corp <dbl>, indirect <dbl>, gst <dbl>, trade <dbl>, tottax_d <dbl>, indiv_d <dbl>, corp_d <dbl>,
#   indirect_d <dbl>, gst_d <dbl>, trade_d <dbl>, matchcode <fct>
```

This dataset however has a lot of missingness. If I would like to use all of the variables of interest in the regression, I would end up without any complete observations (and thus no regression). Although maybe not the most scientific solution, for getting some first results, I would like to identify the bottlenecks in my dataset.

Obviously the first step would be to kick out the variables with the lowest amount of observations,

```
dataobs <- as.data.frame(colSums(!is.na(data))) # Get observations
```

but this does not get me very far. I would like to measure the missingness dependent on the other variables.

I am thinking about what would be the best way to do this and how to implement this in R.

Any ideas?

EDIT: And no I don't want to remove the NA's in my dataset.

EDIT 2: I guess the second step would also still be quite obvious. I should somehow make:

```
dataobs <- as.data.frame(colSums(!is.na(data)))
```

conditional on the dependent variable.

Comment: If you like visual representations, you could try `visdat::vis_miss()`. (http://visdat.njtierney.com/reference/vis_miss.html). If you want to calculate missingness, you could look at what `vis_miss()` is doing when clustering (https://github.com/ropensci/visdat/blob/1f28b70dd1fba9df6ad65f7e14da0c983631a25e/R/vis-miss.R#L82) and work from there.

Comment: That actually worked quite decently. Thank you so much for the tip! Regrettably, I can't distinguish a well discernable patern.

Comment: You can apparently cluster the data. For my dataset (also using `warn_large_data=FALSE`) this however results in a `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 19.2 Gb`.

Comment: That's interesting, since your data is not that big. Maybe you could try to take a sample of your data (explained in the examples)?